# Completely expand all node of a Jtree (including children)

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I found some details on the internet for this problem but the solution does not seem to work.

I want to be able to expand all the nodes ( including the leaf nodes ) of a `JTree`. This is the code I have so far.

```
    tree = new JTree(treeModel);
    tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
    tree.setEditable(true);
    tree.addTreeSelectionListener(treeSelectionListener);
    tree.addMouseListener(mouselistener);
    tree.setCellRenderer(new FileCellRenderer());

      for (int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
            
            tree.expandRow(i);
        }
```

This however does not expand all the leaf nodes. What I get is IMAGE **A** but what I want is IMAGE **B**:

[image: IMAGE A]
[image: IMAGE B]

Comment: Do you have SSCCE? For me it should work.

Comment: It will work as long as the tree isn't more than 2 deep.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a recursive call, as in the following sample:

```
private void expandAllNodes(JTree tree, int startingIndex, int rowCount){
    for(int i=startingIndex;i<rowCount;++i){
        tree.expandRow(i);
    }

    if(tree.getRowCount()!=rowCount){
        expandAllNodes(rowCount, tree.getRowCount());
    }
}
```

Comment: The 7th line is missing the JTree parameter. Change `expandAllNodes(rowCount, tree.getRowCount());` to `expandAllNodes(tree, rowCount, tree.getRowCount());`